# Android Location update is happening twice

Tags: android, service, location

I want to run location update as a service. Now I can able to run the service correctly but the location updation is happening twice, Here is the code,

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


 <service
    android:name=".services.LocationService"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
    android:label="Location Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.service" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

In the Activity Class we are using `startLocationService()` to start the service and `stopLocationService()` to stop the service, Also created a Broadcast Receiver to get the location updation on the Activity Calss.

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
private Intent mLocationServiceIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigtaion_drawer);

    AppController.getInstance().activityResumed();
    broadcastReceiver = createBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(getPackageName()));


    if (!Permissions.hasLocationPermission(this)) {
        Permissions.requestLocationPermission(this, PermissionKeys.LOCATION_REQUEST_HOME_ON_RESUME);
    } else 
        startLocationService();

}


private BroadcastReceiver createBroadcastReceiver() {
    return new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.hasExtra(LocationService.LOCATION_UPDATED)) {
                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                if (b != null) {
                    Location mCurrentLocation = (Location) b.get(LocationService.LOCATION_UPDATED);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}


   //Function To Start the Service
   public void startLocationService() {
        if (mLocationServiceIntent == null)
            mLocationServiceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        startService(mLocationServiceIntent);
    }

    //Function To Stop the Service
    public void stopLocationService() {
        if (mLocationServiceIntent != null)
            stopService(mLocationServiceIntent);
    }
```

**LocationService.java**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    public static final String LOCATION_UPDATED = "LocationUpdated";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "Latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "Longitude";

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static final String TAG = "###LocationService:: ";
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 15000;
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 7f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10.0f);  /* min dist for location change, here it is 10 meter */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    //Check Google play is available or not
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        return ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connected");
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Start Location Updates");
        try {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Location Changed : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra(LOCATION_UPDATED, location);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

    }


   /* LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };*/


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:: "+connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding a condition checking before start the service, 
My updated `startLocationService()` function is like,

```
//Function To Start the Service
   public void startLocationService() {
        if (mLocationServiceIntent == null)
            mLocationServiceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        if(!isServiceRunning(HomeScreenActivity.this, LocationService.class)) {
            startService(mLocationServiceIntent);
        }
    }
```

Here is the function to check if the service is already running or not.

```
//This function is to check the service is already running or not
    public boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.e("ServiceRunning", serviceClass.getSimpleName() + " is alredy running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```